# If $f$ is continuous and positive and $\int_a^b f(x)dx=0$ therefore $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $f$ is continuous and non-negative and $\int_a^b f(x)dx=0$ therefore $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

**My attempts**

Suppose $f\neq 0$, i.e. there is an $x\in ]a,b[$ s.t. $f(x)\neq 0$. Since $f$ is continuous, there is a $\delta>0$ s.t. $f|_{]x-\delta,x+\delta[}> 0$ (we take $\delta$ small enough to have $]x-\delta,x+\delta[\subset ]a,b[$. Therefore $$\int_a^b f(t)dt\geq \int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}f(t)dt>0$$
contradiction. The cas $x=a$ or $x=b$ goes the same but with $f|_{]a,a+\delta[}>0$ or $f|_{]b-\delta,b[}>0$.

Comment: the question makes more sense if the condition is continuous and non-negative

Comment: @DavidHolden: to me positive is $\geq 0$. For $>0$ I would say strictly positive.

Comment: It's not duplicate since my proof is different.

Comment: What's your question, @Rick?

Comment: You did not strictly show that $f > 0$ on an interval $I$ implies that $\int_I f(t)dt > 0$. The answers to the proposed duplicate show how to handle that.

Comment: It's a result I can use :-) @MartinR

Comment: @Rick Nice proof, what are you asking?

Comment: Just if way way to prove it is correct :-) Thanks. But by your last comment, I can say it is :-)